# Float an image between 2 columns of text

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know if it's possible to reproduce in CSS/HTML the effect you see in this magazine, with an image floated between 2 columns of text and the text wrapping around it:

[image: Floated Image]

I know only modern browsers support 2-column layouts, so my questions are:

1. Can this be done in modern browsers?  If so, how?  We are essentially doing a "float:both" but ofc that directive doesn't exist....
2. Is there any backward compatible hack to sort of do it in older browsers?

Finally, if you can do this in HTML/CSS, I would think the image would still have to be square, so that the wrapping effect would not be as organic as it is here.  Would it be possible to reproduce the effect exactly, rather than having the image square with whitespace, eg, to the left and right of Ron Paul's head?  Would you have to slice up the image to accomplish that?

Comment: fwiw, yes you can, but I'd have to hunt up the article describing how. No, you don't need to slice the image.

Comment: Where would HTML coders be if they wouldn't be handling challenging layouts best fit for print? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easily doable (especially for dynamic text). All the techniques have various downsides.

Here's one possible technique for "float center":

http://css-tricks.com/9048-float-center/

For [*modern browsers*](http://caniuse.com/canvas), there's a jQuery plugin that can do it [precisely](http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/example2.html):

http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/

Here's the tedious, manual version that inspired the above jQuery plugin:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sandbags

Answer (score 1):

[Curvelicious](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/raggedfloat/demo.html) Otherwise known as a ragged float by Eric Meyer.
Also [Sandbags](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sandbags/)