# Text to run around the logo

Tags: css

I have a 2 columns text and a logo (with position:fixed) in the middle of the screen.

All I want is that the text runs around the logo without touching it, is that doable?

```
-webkit-column-count:2;
-moz-column-count:2;
column-count:2;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f418og5o/1/

THANKS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100144/two-css3-columns-text-with-an-image-in-middle possible duplicate?

Comment: See this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182577/how-to-wrap-text-around-floating-fixed-image

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588302/float-an-image-between-2-columns-of-text

Comment: The only thing is that I would love the logo to have position:fixed.